# Jetpack Compose - one time animation of color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I need to create following animation in Jetpack:

Text is normally gray, when some event occurs (lets say message arrive) the text become green and fade out slowly back to gray.

I did it with ObectAnimator and its .start() method in "classic old" XML layouts:

```
val colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
                binding!!.tvLiveDataSource, "textColor",
                Color.argb(255, 173, 255, 0), Color.argb(255, 33, 49, 0)
            )
            colorAnim.duration = 5000
            colorAnim.setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())
            colorAnim.start()
```

But I canot find any usable example for Jetpack. All examples are switching between true/false variable and based on it are animating color transition. It is not usable for my case, as I need trigger one time transition from green to gray.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/quick-guide did not find this useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `animateColorAsState` for changing the color of the `Text`.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

```
import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Preview
@Composable
fun Stack025(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var animateBackgroundColor by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val animatedColor by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (animateBackgroundColor) Color.Red else Color.Blue,
        label = "color"
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Sample Text",
            color = animatedColor,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)
        )

        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                animateBackgroundColor = true
                delay(800)
                animateBackgroundColor = false
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Click to receive msg")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag, interesting technique. But the problem is that animateAsState function animates between both states, from BLUE to RED and also from RED to BLUE. I added tween modifier with two seconds and it can be seen. The thing what I need to achieve (and what was provided by ObjectAnimator in XML) is:

Text is normally GRAY -> Message arrived -> Text instantly become GREEN and then slowly (lets say during two seconds) change back to GRAY

Comment: Here the Default color it blue and when you click on button means when message receive it becomes the red and then back to blue. you can increase time of animations

Comment: Yes, I understand, default color is Blue and when message arrive (simulated by click on button), it become to Red. The problem is that this particular phase (Blue -> Red) is also animated. I need to switch to Red instantly and then slowly animate to Blue.

Comment: I modified tween durationMilis on animateBackgroundColor value and it is working perfectly: animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = if(animateBackgroundColor == true) 10 else 3000, easing = LinearEasing), 10ms for Blue->Red and 3000ms for Red->Blue. Many thanks Chirag